# polymer importHref unexpected token

Tags: polymer-1.0

I get an unexpected token '<' when I use

```
this.importHref(_import.link, function () {              
            });
```

and the _import.link has

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
```

I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL for the link href was incorrect. A better error message would be nice.